# Adobe animate and ie8, can it work together

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, polyfills, adobe-animate

For one reason or another my application have to support internet explorer with document mode 8 (I will call that IE8) and we also want to add some interactive animations that are done with adobe animate. The animations are exported as canvas. It works fine with document mode 9, but when using IE8, it throws errors.

When I debug the errors, I can see that the code that adobe animate generated uses Object.defineProperty, witch is not supported from IE8.

After I managed to find a polifill that works

https://gist.github.com/afuggini/85b02644491f130879a8e789a5b1cea8

(I tested it in another place),

Then I used polyfill for bind (since the defineProperty polyfill uses bind), that I took from here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill

Internet explorer just started crashing the page. If I load the page with IE9 all is good, if I use IE8 it just crashes. Without anything in the console it just displays one message in the bottom part of the screen with this text:
"A problem with this webpage caused Internet Explorer to close and reopen the tab"

Can anyone give me any ideas what can I do to make it work.

If someone wants to replicate it, here are the files:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgTpAcs7KGa6hc08BpXtvtMmCPi7Mg

p.s. I know that I can export the same animation as flash swf and use that for IE8, but I am trying to avoid this as much as possible for multiple of reasons.

Comment: I've reprodcued your issue in IE8 mode, but I'm confused that in IE9 mode, there is error information on console tab."Syntax error" It is so strange. I've also wanted to check that the browser compatibility with adobe animate but could not find a professional document. My guess is that it is not compatible and in old version maybe there is not a good way to solve this.

Comment: 10x for the reply. I managed to track what is the issue. It turns out that Adobe Animate uses createjs for in order to make the animations work. Createjs uses some other dependencies inside, and in the createjs site, there is a section explaining the that : "EaselJS 0.8, TweenJS 0.6, PreloadJS 0.6, and SoundJS 0.6 is not compatible with IE8 and below" and they suggest that we shuld use older version for IE8 support. The problem is that replacing the library with older, broke the code generated from Adobe animate. Still have no fix for that